# Issue with ereporter on Google App Engine - Admin message exceeds size limits

Tags: google-app-engine

I am getting the following error when I run a cron job on Google App Engine. I am fairly new this, so I would appreciate your help. The logs says

```
2014-05-15 10:22:00.808 /_ereporter?sender=xxx.xxxx@gmail.com 500 181ms 0kb AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine) module=default version=1
0.1.0.1 - - [14/May/2014:17:22:00 -0700] "GET /_ereporter?sender=xxxx.xxxx@gmail.com HTTP/1.1" 500 176 - "AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine)" "xxx" ms=182 cpu_ms=130 cpm_usd=0.000020 queue_name=__cron task_name=53af0e1a7855b393e1cbc5fc88478bc1 app_engine_release=1.9.4 instance=00c61b117c4d81bfa7ad37bdf4d8dec553a2eb
```

The stack trace is as follows.

```
Admin message exceeds size limits
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1511, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1505, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1253, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1077, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 547, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 545, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ereporter/report_generator.py", line 181, in get
    self.SendReport(report)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ereporter/report_generator.py", line 149, in SendReport
    self.send_mail_to_admins(**mail_args)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/mail.py", line 429, in send_mail_to_admins
    message.send(make_sync_call)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/mail.py", line 1114, in send
    raise ERROR_MAP[e.application_error](e.error_detail)
BadRequestError: Admin message exceeds size limits
```